# Multiple cv-decompositions of a type

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, type-systems

The example in [[conv.qual]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#1) says that the type `const int **` has two cv-decompositions.

> A cv-decomposition of a type T is a sequence of cv_i and P_i such that T is
>
> “cv_0 P_0 cv_1 P_1 ⋯ cv_{n−1} P_{n−1} cv_n U”
>
> for n≥0, where each cv_i is a set of cv-qualifiers ([basic.type.qualifier]), and
>   each P_i is “pointer to” ([dcl.ptr]), “pointer to member of class Ci of
>   type” ([dcl.mptr]), “array of N_i”, or “array of unknown bound of”
>   ([dcl.array]). If P_i designates an array, the cv-qualifiers cv_{i+1} on the element type are also taken as the cv-qualifiers cv_i of the array.
>   [ Example: **The type denoted by the type-id `const int **` has two cv-decompositions, taking U as “`int`” and as “pointer to `const int`”**.
>   — end example ]
>   The n-tuple of cv-qualifiers after the first one in the longest cv-decomposition of T, that is, cv_1,cv_2,…,cv_n, is called the cv-qualification signature of T.

Why the type does not have three decompositions, the third one with n=0, cv_0 empty and U="pointer to pointer to `const int`"?

Comment: Then it's not a decomposition?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer there is no P_0 if n=0.

Comment: The condition on `n` was changed 4 months ago in [this commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/573152d081f7052f4ebe7678d58f94714f2b973b) (http://wg21.link/p1359#2051) (was `n > 0`). Looks like they forgot to update the example. You may try to open an issue or PR in https://github.com/cplusplus/draft

Comment: mkay, I've submitted an issue https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2940

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why the type does not have three decompositions

It has, but the example is slightly out of sync with the normative part. The normative wording was changed relatively recently by [this commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/573152d081f7052f4ebe7678d58f94714f2b973b) replacing the condition in the definition of cv-decomposition from `n > 0` to `n ≥ 0`.

The PR fixing the issue in the example is [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2942).